# Fundamental theorem of arithmetic for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Every polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$ 
can be uniquely written as
            \begin{equation}
       f(x) = \alpha (p_1(x))^{a_1} \cdot (p_2(x))^{a_2} \cdot ... \cdot (p_k(x))^{a_k},
      \end{equation}
            where $\alpha \in K, a_i \in \mathbb{N}$, with $p_i(x)$ irreducible for all $1 \leq i < k$.

Proof: I could prove the decomposition using induction on the degree of polynomial $f(x)$ but couldn't think of a way to prove uniqueness. Please help me.

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}{p_1(x)}$ has a unique decomposition by induction on the degree of $f$.

Comment: You need to require the $p_i$ to be monic (to avoid identities like $2(x -1) = (2x - 2)$).

Comment: @EliotG: I don't think it's a duplicate: Gauss's lemma is a somewhat harder result than the the result that $K[x]$ has unique factorisation when $K$ is a field.

Comment: Euclidean domain $\implies$ PID $\implies$ UFD

Comment: @hardmath: and the reverse implications are false and it turns out to be a bit easier to prove that $K[x]$ is a euclidean domain and hence a UFD when $K$ is known to be a field.

Comment: @RobA: I agree with you.  The degree argument makes it easier to show irreducible elements are primes, which makes the factorization unique (up to unit factors). (The degree argument also helps to show units of $K[X]$ are just the nonzero constants.)

Comment: @Rob Not clear what you mean, easier than *what*?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I meant that it is easier to show that $R[x]$ is a UFD when $R$ is given to be a field rather than when $R$ is only given to be a UFD.